# How to use ajax to load a row of youtube videos, then go onto the next row

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I know it is a bit vague of a question, but I have a webpage that is just a wall of youtube videos. I have the videos separated into divs called rows and there are about 3, maybe 4 videos per row. In my script I am using a jQuery function to create SWFobjects for each video and I have some simple php creating each row of videos inside a wordpress loop.

My question is; is there a way to load a row, 3 or 4 videos, and after that completes to continue the wordpress loop to the next row and so on. I believe my answer lies with ajax but I have no experience with it. I know jquery has some great tools and methods to use to help with ajax, but I dont know where to start and what I am even looking for.

Literally all that webpage does is loop through this bit of code below, this is reduced by a bit. But it runs this function 3 times then goes to the next row and does it 3 more times until wordpress says there are no more posts in that category. How can i get ajax to do one row at a time and not 'all at once'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var youtubeID = '<?php echo $urlYoutube; //pass the php var to js var?>';
    var divID = '<?php echo $divName;?>';
    getVideoSML(youtubeID, divID);
</script>
```

A nice and generous 'push' in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, if not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var youtubeID = '<?php echo $urlYoutube; //pass the php var to js var?>';
    var divID = '<?php echo $divName;?>';
    getVideoSML(youtubeID, divID);
</script>
```

This is not how you pass data from PHP to Javascript. You should read something about [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). There are a lot of tutorials on the internet, and everything is made even too easy by [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (take a look at that too).

I don't think I got the question but I think you are having a problem understanding loops. AJAX is just a way of load a page dinamically and asynchronous. If I got it right you should use 2 loops:

```
$vps = 4; // number of videos per row
while (/* there are rows to be printed */) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $vpr; $i++) {
        /* print the video */
    }
}
```

Comment: For what i need passing the data that way, gets it done cause it will only ever be a short string to pass. As far as the loops, wordpress takes care of that WHILE loop already and I wrote a bit of code for the FOR loop too, but I think what i want to know is about the printing order. Aren't all the iterations of the loop done then the browser prints all the data at once, therefore increasing the entire pages loading? If so, I would like to finish loading the page then start loading in the rows

Comment: @NilsR, then you need to load the rows with AJAX. PHP will show the final page only when everything is loaded and yes, increasing the page load. Using AJAX is a good method to make the page load and then load each video; just consider the case when a user has Javascript disabled (yet AJAX doesn't work).

Comment: do you know any links i can read or way to implement the ajax in this scenario or anything to help me get the ball rolling?

Comment: @NilsR, Just Google them. Anyway it's not that hard to understand: AJAX is a way to do asynchronous calls to a PHP page. Basically what you do is take jQuery and run an AJAX call (usually with POST method) to a PHP page that return something. The JSON is the format of how data is passed from PHP to Javascript and viceversa. If this doesn't help, then take a look at [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development/)